# dd with obs and seek makes file of unexpected size

Tags: linux, dd

I'm learning to use `dd` by experimentally playing with its arguments. I would like to create a 10-byte file. I thought the following would work:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=./foo count=1 bs=1 obs=9 seek=1
```

...because of these comments from the man page:

> ```
>    obs=BYTES
>           write BYTES bytes at a time (default: 512)
>    seek=N skip N obs-sized blocks at start of output
> ```

...but it does not; it creates a 2-byte file:

```
>ls -l foo
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 2 Mar 28 16:05 foo
```

My workaround has been:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=./foo count=1 bs=1 obs=1 seek=9
```

But for my learning, I'd like to understand why the first version does not work. Thank you.

Comment: `bs= 1` and `obs=9` conflict, and apparently the `bs= ` overrides the `obs= ` specification.  Try using the more specific `ibs=1` instead of the `bs=1`.  Check the source code to confirm.

Comment: @sawdust You're correct: thanks for the tip. Please post as an answer if you'd like the point.

Comment: crosspost of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/354460/dd-with-obs-and-seek-makes-file-of-unexpected-size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your simultaneous use of `bs= 1` and `obs=9` conflict, since the bs parameter specifies both input and output block sizes.
Apparently the `bs=` overrides the `obs=` specification.

Try using the more specific `ibs=1` instead of the `bs=1`.